# prevent element from cancel hover

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple `.hover` on a text element:

```
$('#menu_1').hover(function() { 
    $('#overlay_1').fadeIn('slow');
       }, function() { 
    $('#overlay_1').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

what happens is, that an element displays over the text element. But this element bothers the `.hover()` because the cursor is now on the new displayed element, not on the text anymore. Is there a way to prevent this?

to mention: I want the displayed element above the text

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c8fqvbcp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll can just place the `#overlay_1` element inside your `#menu_1` element so that even when you're hovering over `#overlay_1` you're still hovering over `#menu_1` as well.

```
<elem id="menu_1">
    <elem id="overlay_1"></elem>
</elem>
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/3k3squxL/).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this through css. Give the element that appears on top the following style rule:
`pointer-events: none;`

This way the cursor will 'ignore' the element and your hover-effect still works. However, this does mean the element on top is no longer clickable.

Edit:

```
#overlay_1 {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8fqvbcp/2/

Edit: I wasn't aware of it, but it was pointed out to me browser support isn't ideal: http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: Worth noting that CSS's `pointer-events` property [isn't supported on IE10 or lower](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), meaning this will potentially not work for almost 10% of users.

Comment: should note not all browsers support it though

Comment: thank you, this is pretty much what I was searching for. Chrossbrowser check, or is it modern only? Edit: thanks guys

Comment: Added a footnote about the (lack of) browser support. I wasn't aware of this myself.